# How to get all the user IDs of people who are using your Facebook application

Tags: facebook

Is there a way to get the user IDs of all the people who are using your Facebook application?

Answer (score 20):

Doing an extensive research I concluded that ***there's NO method to do this***!

**What I have found:**
An old REST API called [`friends.getAppUsers`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/friends.getappusers/) that gets all the IDs of the user's friends that authorized the application.

**What I wish I had found:**
After reading the `App Login` section in the [authentication document](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/):

> In addition to User Login, Facebook
>   Platform support **App Login** using
>   the OAuth 2.0 Client Credential flow.
>   App Login allows you to take various
>   administrative actions for your app,
>   such as retrieving Insights data or
>   approving Requests.

I thought the [application](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/application/) object would have a direct method for this (similar to `accounts`):

```php
$facebook->api("/APP_ID/users");
```

But I was wrong. And then with the introduction of the [insights](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/insights) feature, I was shocked that you can only get the *count* of the User IDs!

**What you can do:**
Storing the User ID in your DB as soon as a user authorize your application and if your application already has users (most likely the case), check if you have a record for each user that interacts with your application in your DB...this way, you'll get the User IDs for your active users in no time.

Comment: yeah that seems to be the best solution to store it in an extra db.
but i thougth it would be nice .. not to store user data.

so you also can get only one uid out of the event owner / creator content. also the event shows both of them.

Answer (score 0):

Just a little more on this - I managed to find a lot of the userIDs I was looking for by doing basic Graph API searches and then checking they were valid with my app.

Search an email address or username here:- https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET

`QUERY: https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=user@email.com&type=user`

If you get a match or more than one, you can check it is valid as install on the FQL query button of the same explorer:-

```
SELECT uid FROM user WHERE uid = *USER_ID_TO_SEARCH* AND is_app_user = 1
```

If it appears as a uid, you're good - they're valid. This helped me get to what I needed (when I hadn't got some of my app users info on signup).

Comment: I couldn't figure out how to search an email from the graph api explorer. What syntax did you use? I tried 'SELECT name FROM user where contact_email = email@gmail.com' but it doesn't seem to like emails

Comment: That search does not work in the new api (3) there is no type=user

Answer (score 0):

```
GET /v2.10/{app-id}/accounts
```

You will get all the accounts for the application

Comment: This will get you application test accounts