# Graph API get information on facebook link shared

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

is that possible we can get the information from facebook API whether graph or REST or FQL regarding user sharing. Such as video or post or anything can share via facebook and it is shared by a list of user, with profile id or user name. I found something like this http://appshack.tv/2011/03/likes/ but it is just the counter, lack of information. Any way can do? Coz I found that facebook not stated everything in the documentation. Some trick is found from third party side.

Answer (score 0):

No you can't get the user ids. Facebook will do their best **NOT** to share the user id with you "unless" they (the users) authorize your application.

And guess what....you can't even get the list of the users who are using **YOUR** application! (You can only get the count!)
Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4776881/how-to-get-all-userids-of-people-who-are-using-your-facebook-application/4777544#4777544).