# How can I determine which friends of the currently logged in user are also using my app?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

The [Graph API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/) makes it easy for me to determine who the friends of the current user are.  I have two questions:

1. Is it possible, using the Graph API, to determine the list of users for the currently authenticated application?
2. Is it possible to determine the friends of the current user who are also users of my application (the intersection of my app's users and the current user's friends)?  Is this possible using FQL?

Comment: i think you can do this with php and mysql

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. No, This is not possible. Refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4776881/how-to-get-all-userids-of-people-who-are-using-your-facebook-application/4777544#4777544).
2. There's a rest method called [`friends.getAppUsers`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/friends.getappusers/) for this. Or you could use FQL:

   ```
   SELECT uid,name FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=me()) AND is_app_user=1
   ```

Comment: As soon as I posted this it occurred to me that I have basic information for my app's users in my own database (as you suggested in your other post).  Thanks very much for the FQL snippet as well.  It is nice to know that there is an alternate method of getting this information if I have performance problems.  Thanks for your help!