# Facebook Graph API equivalent of friends.getAppUsers?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm wanting to re-write my Facebook canvas application after Facebook deprecated some of its technologies, namely FBML and the old REST API.

One of my app's functionality though was to show which of the app user's friends were also users, and a "Suggest to friends" link. However, this friends list was produced with an old REST API call, specifically the `friends.getAppUsers` endpoint.

What is the Graph API equivalent of this endpoint? As I'm wanting to remove all dependencies from the old REST API in the new version of my app.

Comment: Also note that this can be done by [FQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5771056/how-can-i-determine-which-friends-of-the-currently-logged-in-user-are-also-using/5772614#5772614), but `fql.query` is still uses the old Rest api.