# Facebook Canvas App - Finding all users who have installed the app

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

How do I find out all users who have installed my canvas app ? Is there a UI on Facebook for it or do I need to query an API ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get all userids of people who are using your facebook application.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4776881/how-to-get-all-userids-of-people-who-are-using-your-facebook-application)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can't be done as per this - [How to get all the user IDs of people who are using your Facebook application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4776881/how-to-get-all-userids-of-people-who-are-using-your-facebook-application/4777544#4777544)

I would suggest use you to use the depreceated REST API call once to save all the IDs of the users, and then add a new user to that list (keep on saving it in a db).

Answer (score 2):

See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/insights/#Metrics

You can check the **application_installed_users** value to figure out how many users have installed your app.

EDIT: this requires the use of the Facebook FQL interface, as covered at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/

Comment: Isn't it possible to get the user ids of the people who installed the app ?

Comment: Interesting idea, but it doesn't give the user IDs, which I think is what the OP is after.