# Facebook App User information

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-fql

I have a facebook Canvas App. Once the User authorizes the app, I am storing the facebook user name.

I want to collect more info about the user. I read the following posts.

[get list of facebook users who are using specific application using FQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9081147/get-list-of-facebook-users-who-are-using-specific-application-using-fql)

[Facebook Canvas App - Finding all users who have installed the app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5965763/facebook-canvas-app-finding-all-users-who-have-installed-the-app)

[How to get all the user IDs of people who are using your Facebook application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4776881/how-to-get-all-the-user-ids-of-people-who-are-using-your-facebook-application/4777544#4777544)

Once I store the username, if I want additional information how do I get it. Like Email, location and so on(assuming the app had extended permissions). Can I get these any time once I have the User name and App Access token?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So long as you have the user's `username` or `id` and a valid `access_token` for that user with the required permissions, you can query this information at any time.

You should store both the `username` and the `access_token` to make this work.

Keep in mind that some of this information is available without an `access_token`. On the flip side, users can restrict their privacy settings so some of these items will not be visible to your app.

Comment: So, there is a difference between User Access token and App Access token correct? And If I store the User access token once they are on the canvas page, wouldn't it expire?

Comment: Yes. You'll need to refresh the access token each time they visit. And yes, there is a difference. You can do some tasks with either one, but things like posting to a user's timeline require a user token, and certain app tasks require an app token.