# How can I query the Facebook Graph to get users who previously connected with my application?

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

How do you query the Facebook Graph to get all the users who have connected with your application?  I am not storing their user ID, email or any other data from the user when they first connected with the app. Is there a way to get this data retroactively?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get all userids of people who are using your facebook application.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4776881/how-to-get-all-userids-of-people-who-are-using-your-facebook-application)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably out of luck then, as you have to have at least the user ID to query the [`user`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/user/) FQL table. Your best bet is to implement something that recaptures old installs as existing users come back to your application and capture the data at that time.