# how can I see a list of everyone who is using my iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook

I incorporated the new facebook sdk into my iPhone/iPad app update which just went live yesterday. Per iTunes connect 1100 people have already updated. My insights on FB are behind which I understand. However, when I go to my app's FB page it shows some of my friends using my app (not "liking" it, but using it). How can I get a list of ALL my friends using it, and of EVERYONE using it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to get a full listing of your app's users - you'd need to store this in your own database. You can check if any particular user has authorised your app with a call to `/[UID]?fields=installed` in the Graph API using your app's access token or a user access token

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can't (for privacy reasons, I'm sure).

I have seen people trying, though: [How to get all the user IDs of people who are using your Facebook application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4776881/how-to-get-all-userids-of-people-who-are-using-your-facebook-application/4777544#4777544)