# Get all users who are using my facebook application

Tags: php, facebook

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get all the user IDs of people who are using your Facebook application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4776881/how-to-get-all-the-user-ids-of-people-who-are-using-your-facebook-application)

How to get all users which are using the facebook application ?

Can I tretrieve all my users who are using the facebook AP and get the Access token, becouse now I have only an userId from my facebook Ap, i wan't to get the toke, so I can access more info about them. Can I do this otherway ?

Answer (score 0):

i have learned that i have to store facebook user id on my own db at auth time (and deauthorize callback to remove),but  i would be happy to admit i'm wrong

Comment: I have the user ID, but i need more info about the user, I don't have the Token

Answer (score 0):

No, you can get an access token only if a user is actively interacting with your app.

The most you could do is query the API for information of the friends of your actual user – therefore you have to get friends permissions from the user first, and it gives you extended data only for those friends of the user that have not prevented apps from accessing that data in their settings.