# How to retrieve all users data associated with my Facebook Application via Python code?

Tags: python, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-3.0

I created an application on Facebook for my research project. I, therefore, submitted some fields that I wanted to collect from the users that are going to associate with my app (e.g., user_likes, user_posts). When they associate with my app, how can I retrieve their information using the Facebook-SDK for Python? Is there a way to get a list of associated users of my Facebook App?

I have seen that I can get from the Graph API Explorer all the Test Users of my app using this command:

```
(<<APP-ID>>?fields=accounts)
```

If I turn my app available publicly, this field "accounts" will return all the real users associated with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to get a list of associated users of my Facebook App?

No, you would have to store all users in your own database. There is no API to get all authorized users.

`/me/accounts` returns all Pages the user manages.

Very old, but still valid: [How to get all the user IDs of people who are using your Facebook application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4776881/how-to-get-all-the-user-ids-of-people-who-are-using-your-facebook-application)

Comment: But how can I store all the users in my own database if I can't retrieve their information? I mean, I can, at least, retrieve the user's IDs that are associated with my app?

Comment: you store them right when they authorize your app, or when they hit your app again.

Comment: I see now. Really thanks for your dedicated time and help.